# Restore iOS backup without user interaction

Tags: ios

I would like to automate some iOS devices in a device farm. They are supposed to be able to make a backup and then restore this backup automatically  without any further user input.

I am using idevicebackup2 to make a backup and restore it. After the backup one has to manually click through the upcoming menus. I tried to use webdriveragent to automate this process. I can connect to the device and control it remotely. However, once I restore the backup and the starting menu comes up webdriveragent looses the connection and is not able to reconnect to it again. The error message it gives is:

```
    WebDriverAgentRunner:
        WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: Unable to launch com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner. (Underlying error: Device is currently locked with a passcode.  Please unlock the device and try again.)))
```

I do not have a passcode set at the time of the backup or at the time of the restore. Does anyone know how I can get the device out of this state in a way that can be automated?